# Use the answer and update it for the another user who has some different requirement

Tags: discussion

If there is a answer given for any question, can I use it and modify it in another user's question?  Of course he made a different requirement, and I had modify the answer as per the user requirement.

Is this a wrong way to give the answer? If the answer fulfil the user's need and he accept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the user contents on these sites is licensed under the Creative Commons CC BY-SA 3.0, with attribution required (see the footer). So you can share and reuse that contents as much as you want, on the original site or elsewhere, as long as you abide by that license.

In the case you state, yes that would be fine if the changes required are somewhat substantial. Simply link back to the answer you're adapting so everyone knows where it comes from, and explain how you adapted it to fit the new question.
Make sure your answer is complete in itself though, posts that contain barely more than a link aren't viewed very well here. (Even when they are internal links.)

If the changes required are very basic (i.e. anyone with basic knowledge of the problem domain should be able to adapt it themselves), then voting (or flagging) to close the new question as a duplicate would probably be the better option.

Comment: thanks mat i was worried so much because somebody comment on my answer that takes from some other answer. so how should i reply him?

Comment: Can you share a link to that post/comment so we can see the context?

Comment: yes that is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795997/get-the-numeric-items-from-string/21796043#21796043 suggest me anything you want.

Comment: Just ignore it. Looks like that user was annoyed because that question (or variations) has been asked and answered a lot. And since it's relatively simple, a lot of the answers look alike. If you did inspire yourself from an existing answer, link to it. If you didn't, don't worry. There's only so many ways of matching digits in a string.

Comment: thanks Mat i was so much worried. i love this site. because it provide me a way that i can explore my logics and knowledge and share with everyone.

Comment: @SatishSharma: a good idea is also to check that the question isn't a duplicate (like it was in this case), though what you did there seems fine to me (with the proper attribution and perhaps an explanation of what you changed).